# sp_executesql Expects statement... Well, I give it to it

Tags: sql-server

I'm having an issue with this procedure.
Here's the code

```
declare @sql nvarchar(4000)
set @sql =  N'SELECT @resp2 = count(*) from '+ @NameTable + ' where datum = ''1'' or datum = ''2''    '
    EXEC sp_executesql
    @query = @sql,
    @params = N'@resp2 INT OUTPUT', 
    @resp2 = @resp2 OUTPUT
```

> "Procedure expects parameter '@statement' of type
>   'ntext/nchar/nvarchar'."

Am I not giving the statement? (@sql)

All I want to do is set a value to @resp2 in the execution.

Comment: Works fine for me. Sure you are looking at the correct bit of code?

Comment: I took 10 minutes to separate every piece of code by comments of if's and the problem seems to be here. Besides none of the other code can produce the error the server sends. :/

Comment: Works for me too. I believe that - somehow - in your original code @sql is not nvarchar but varchar.

Comment: you are right Nikola. @SQL is varchar. Does it change anything in this code?

Comment: sp_executesql works with nvarchar. Just declare @sql as one and there should be no ill effects. But, if you worry about side-effects, declare `@sqln` before sp_executesql and assign `@sql` to it.

Comment: that's right, it's working now! @NikolaMarkovinović. Post it as a Answer and you'll get the points! Thanks a lot, I missed that little trick about sp_executesql

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [the manual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001(v=sql.105).aspx), you should provide a value for the parameter called **`@statement`**, but you are supplying it as `@query`.

So it should be:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(4000)
set @sql =  N'SELECT @resp2 = count(*) from '+ @NameTable + ' where datum = ''1'' or datum = ''2''    '
EXEC sp_executesql
@statement = @sql,
@params = N'@resp2 INT OUTPUT', 
@resp2 = @resp2 OUTPUT
```

Just follow the manual, and you'll be okay.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine for me on SQL2008 R2. What version are you running on? You could try replacing your last line there with:

```
exec (@sql)
```